# Structured Tool Agent Finish

Tags: python, agent, langchain

I have created a structured tool using Langchain and I want to output directly agent finish after using this tool. Is there any option in kwargs to pass to that when initlaizing the tool? Or I just have to remake the tool using Base Tool.

```
 Tool(
            name="GetStock",
            func=get_stock,
            description=get_stock_description,
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `BaseTool` with a `return_redirect` flag to achieve that.

```py
class GetStockTool(BaseTool):

    name = "Custom tool"
    description = "Custom tool for some task"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.return_direct = True

    def _run(self, query: str):
        """Return stock data"""
        # logic to return data

    def _arun(self, query: str):
        raise NotImplementedError("This tool does not support async")
```

`BaseTool` [examples](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/tools/custom_tools#subclassing-the-basetool-class)

Comment: Found an easier method. Posted as the answer Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will to do the Job.

```
 Tool(
            name="GetStock",
            func=get_stock,
            description=get_stock_description,
            return_direct = True
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Axen_Rangs pointed out you could try setting return_direct = True, this should do the job. For more details check: https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/tools/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35710525)